# XML 2 mySQL Fatal error: Call to a member function item()

Tags: php, mysql, xml, import, tags

actual i trying to import an XML into MySQL

```
for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
    $title = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $link  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $image_link  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('image_link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $price  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $brand  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('brand')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $availability = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('availability')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;  
    $id = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;  
    $product_type = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('product_type')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;  
    $description = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;  
    $sale_price = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('sale_price')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

after adding the last Object `Saleprice` i get the error message

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function item() on null in

I think the problem is that the value "sale price" is not set in every item

but how can i fix it - that if the value is set > the value gets imported into MySQL

thanks in advance

---

XML Sample

```
<item>
    <g:id>4</g:id>
    <title>sadsadsdsadsadsadsadasd</title>
    <description>dddddddd</description>
    <g:product_type>aaaaaaaaa</g:product_type>
    <link>https://www.xyz.de</link>
    <g:image_link>https://www.xyz.de/600x600.jpg</g:image_link>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
    <g:availability>out of stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>5,95</g:price>
        <g:sale_price>4,99</g:sale_price>
        <g:brand>asdasdsddsn</g:brand>
    <g:gtin>137</g:gtin>
    <g:mpn></g:mpn>
    <g:shipping>
        <g:country>DE</g:country>
        <g:service>Standard</g:service>
        <g:price>7,99</g:price>
    </g:shipping>
    <pubDate>Fri, 07 Dec 2018 12:10:02 CET</pubDate></item>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the XML which you are processing.

Comment: @NigelRen of cource

Answer (score 0):

You are going accessing the first node of a list without checking if the list has nodes.

```
$sale_price =  
  $xmlObject // DOM node list
    ->item($i) // DOM node at index $i
    ->getElementsByTagName('sale_price') // list of'sale_price' descendant elements
    ->item(0) // first node in list - NULL if list is empty
    ->childNodes // child nodes list - this includes text nodes
    ->item(0)  // first node in list - NULL if list is empty
    ->nodeValue; // node content
```

The error happens if here is no `sale_price` element (in one of your context nodes). So if using the DOM methods you will have to check each level to avoid this.

Or you start using XPath:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<products>
  <product>
    <title>With sale_price</title>
    <sale_price>42.00</sale_price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <title>Without sale_price</title>
  </product>
</products>
XML;

$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($document);

foreach($xpath->evaluate('//product') as $product) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $product), ': ';
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(sale_price)', $product), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
With sale_price: 42.00 
Without sale_price:
```

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return a node list with a location path expression like `//product` and scalar values if you cast the node list inside the expression. `string(title)` will fetch all `title` child nodes into a list and cast the first node into a string (return its text content) if it can not find a node it will return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of approaching this, the way you are currently doing it can be shortened so that there isn't so much code.  With the sale_price, this fetches a list of the elements and if there aren't any, defaults it to 0...

```
for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
    $title = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $link  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $image_link  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('image_link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $price  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $brand  = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('brand')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $availability = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('availability')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $id = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $product_type = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('product_type')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $description = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $sale_price = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('sale_price');
    $sale_price =  ( count($sale_price) > 0 )? $sale_price->item(0)->nodeValue : 0;

    $sql   = "Insert into xxxxxxxxx (title, link, image_link, price, brand, availability, id, product_type, description, sale_price) VALUE ('$title', '$link', '$image_link', '$price', '$brand', '$availability', '$id', '$product_type', '$description', '$sale_price')";
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or you could switch to SimpleXML which is much less code.  Here you can use PHP's `isset()` to check if there is a value and set to 0 if not.  In PHP 7 you can also use null coalesce (`??`) to do the same...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");   // Load from a file
// $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData);   // Load from a string
foreach ( $xml->item as $item ) {
    $g = $item->children("g", true);

    $title = (string)$item->title;
    $link  = (string)$item->link;
    $image_link  = (string)$g->image_link;
    $price  = (string)$g->price;
    $brand  = (string)$g->brand;
    $availability = (string)$g->availability;
    $id = (string)$g->id;
    $product_type = (string)$g->product_type;
    $description = (string)$item->description;
    $sale_price = (string)(isset($g->sale_price) ?$g->sale_price: 0);
    // $sale_price = (string)($g->sale_price ?? 0);   // PHP 7+

    $sql   = "Insert into xxxxxxxxx (title, link, image_link, price, brand, availability, id, product_type, description, sale_price) VALUE ('$title', '$link', '$image_link', '$price', '$brand', '$availability', '$id', '$product_type', '$description', '$sale_price')";
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The only complication in SimpleXML is that it has to take into account the namespace, so any element with a g prefix ( e.g. id ) needs to be read from the `$g` variable which is all of the g prefixed elements from the node.